# Facebook Login in Codeigniter Facebook\Facebook class not found

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, facebook-graph-api

I m trying to integtrate Facebook login in my website. I downloaded and integrated all library files in my web App directory.
But i get an error.

> An uncaught Exception was encountered Type: Error
>
> Message: Class 'Facebook\Facebook' not found
>
> Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\fyp\application\libraries\Facebook.php
>
> Line Number: 68
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\fyp\application\controllers\User_authentication.php
>   Line: 8 Function: library
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\fyp\index.php Line: 315 Function: require_once

C:\xampp\htdocs\fyp\application\libraries\Facebook.php here is code of Line No 68

```
if (!isset($this->fb))
{
    require_once 'facebook-php-sdk/autoload.php';
    $this->fb = new FB([
    'app_id'=> $this->config->item('facebook_app_id'),
    'app_secret'=> $this->config->item('facebook_app_secret'),
    'default_graph_version' => $this->config->item('facebook_graph_version')
]);
}
```

at the top of file i added line

```
use Facebook\Facebook as FB;
```

Answer (score 0):

At the top of the file you have not required Facebook API yet.

Try to move `require_once` to the top also

```
require_once 'facebook-php-sdk/autoload.php';
use Facebook\Facebook as FB;
```